# How to add a two nib UITableViewCell in one Uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm new in iOS developing,  it is possible to add two different nib cells in one tableview, if yes can u display any example.
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register 2 nibs

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Cell1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Cell2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell2")
```

and in the datasource you select them by indexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellName = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) ? "Cell1" : "Cell2"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellName, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

[image]

---

> what if i wanna to add more then two nib files...

```
for i in 1...3 {
    let cellID = "Cell" + String(i)
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: cellID, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
}
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellID = (indexPath.row % 3) + 1
    let cellName = "Cell" + String(cellID)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellName, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

[image]